# matplotlib animation show nothing

Tags: matplotlib

I run the demo from [Advanced Visualisation of Lorenz Attractor](https://github.com/SkalskiP/ILearnDeepLearning.py/blob/master/03_animated_graphs/Advanced%20Visualisation%20of%20Lorenz%20Attractor.ipynb)

I run this code in win10 Python3.5 by using CMD. and I change the

```
anim.save('lorenz_attractor.gif', dpi=80, writer='imagemagick')
```

to

```
plt.show()
```

but the figure show nothing like this:
[image]

Where is it wrong?

I search in the internet but can't find the reason.

Comment: Remove `animated=True` whereever it occurs.